# how do i tie an event to multiple listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, sender

i have a piece of code that id like to use for multiple listboxes. basically wherever the mouse is, select that index

```
driversListBox.SelectedIndex = driversListBox.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
```

how would i write this so that i can tie this code to 2-3 listboxes and the code applies to whoever the sender is?

ive tried casting like below but no luck.

```
(Listbox)sender.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: simply register same event handler for all

Comment: And use correct syntax (parantheses): `((Listbox)sender).IndexFromPoint(...)`

Comment: @RenéVogt you are right, but check out the answer from Gusman + his comment - he explains why `as` is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hook all the lists to the same event:

```
list1.MouseMove += CheckMove;
list2.MouseMove += CheckMove;
//...
listN.MouseMove += CheckMove;
```

Then on the event handler:

```
var currentList = sender as ListBox;
//Now you can use currentList as it points to the list 
//which fired the event.
```

Comment: Was about to answer exactly that, but instead of `sender as ListBox` i wouldve used `((Listbox)sender).IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);` , it doesn't matter, just wanted to point out that op made an error, but the approach was ok

Comment: "as" clausule is safer, and strangely faster, it generates only two lines of IL while a direct cast generates four.